# Weird result from pyqt example: an image viewer

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm a beginner of PyQt, and I'm reading some examples in tutorials.

When I build an image viewer from example, I find the result is weird.

https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/examples/widgets/imageviewer.py

Why there is a blank area on the top left of main window? How can I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white rectangle is the `self.imageLabel` object. It is white because of the `self.imageLabel.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)` in the main window constructor. Just comment it out and the rectangle will disappear.

The side effect of this will be that if you open a transparent image, its background will be dark gray (as the background of the rest of the window inside) and not white. If you want it white, move the line `self.imageLabel.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)` to the end of the `open` method and indent it four spaces.